# Can I trademark a logo that contains a font licensed under SIL OFL?

Tags: united-kingdom, intellectual-property, trademark

I am trying to determine whether I am able to use an OFL font in my UK trademark.

From the research I have performed myself, I have determined that OFL fonts can be used in logos, as shown here: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#c26665c2

At this point I would assume this means trademarking a logo that contains an OFL font would be fine as a lot of logos are trademarked.

I scanned the page for any mention of the word trademark and found this: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=OFL-FAQ_web#69733fb4

> 3.7 If a trademark is claimed in the OFL font, does that trademark need to remain in modified fonts?
>
> Answer: Yes. Any trademark notices must remain in any derivative fonts
>   to respect trademark laws, but you may add any additional trademarks
>   you claim, officially registered or not. For example if an OFL font
>   called "Foo" contains a notice that "Foo is a trademark of Acme", then
>   if you rename the font to "Bar" when creating a Modified Version, the
>   new trademark notice could say "Foo is a trademark of Acme Inc. - Bar
>   is a trademark of Roadrunner Technologies Ltd.". Trademarks work
>   alongside the OFL and are not subject to the terms of the licensing
>   agreement. The OFL does not grant any rights under trademark law. Bear
>   in mind that trademark law varies from country to country and that
>   there are no international trademark conventions as there are for
>   copyright. You may need to significantly invest in registering and
>   defending a trademark for it to remain valid in the countries you are
>   interested in. This may be costly for an individual independent
>   designer.

I am trying to determine if this means I can or can't use the OFL font in a trademark, but the terminology is confusing me and this is where I would like assistance.

As for the logo itself, it is 4 letters long all of which use the OFL font. The fourth letter is heavily modified to make the logo a little more unique so that it is not purely made up from the font.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you quote from the FAQ is about retaining trademark notices in derivative fonts you may create and distribute. It has nothing whatsoever with *using* the font to create a trademarked logo.

But to answer your question: Yes, you may trademark a logo that contains a font licensed under SIL OFL.

SIL OFL is a *copyleft* license, but an explicit exemption is provided for "documents" created using the font:

> The requirement for fonts to remain under this license does not apply to any document created using the Font Software.

A logo is a document created using the font, and it can me made proprietary by trademarking it.